# Prestashop, Admin user access issue

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with the access of my admin user to the backoffice of the prestashop store.

The sequence I use is to enter user and password and it does not enter in the admin side.

The weird thing is that when I enter the right user and password does not return me any message. I have entered a wrong password on purpose and it returns me an error message (that is what I expect).

I have changed the password using the “forgot password” method and I have also do a process of updating it manually through this process:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/4843-lost-password-the-solution-is-in-the-forum-but-in-french/

and it has not worked either.

I have checked the whole environment and I was not able to find anything strange. I have looked for other similar situations and I was not able to find other reasons.

What could be happening?

What else should I check?

Best regards

Comment: Is this a programming problem ?

Comment: Could you please enable errors and check again ? https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/enable-error-reporting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have enabled error reporting and I have repeated the action. Once I have entered the user/password again it does not show anything. just the frame of the page and a white square in the middle, so I understand that is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ps_employee` table.

Manually reset password for your admin user.

Edit record,

set password '`MD5`' type. enter new password in value input type and just after your newpassword put your **_COOKIE_KEY_** which you can get from `config/settings.inc.php`.

Then check.

Your issue will be solved.

Comment: hello, I have done the steps you have commented, and it has not worked.

Comment: remove cache/class_index.php file and then check

Comment: I have accessed to the file system and I have removed it, then I have tried to access to the system. The error is still the same. After that I have checked that the system itself has created the file "cache/class_index.php" again.

Comment: I have change the password manually again and now there is something different. Now when I enter the user/password there is an error message: “There is one error. the employee does not existor the password is wrong”

Comment: Check your `ps_employee` table. Check for email field. Also check active column.

Comment: hello Vijay, I have checked the e-mail and it's right. I have checked the Active column has "1" as value. I understand this is the right active value.